# loading data from iframe tag in an html file using perl

Tags: javascript, html, xml, perl, iframe

I am writing a perl script that gets data from html file. I can navigate to the page easily using `WWW::Mechanize` and print output file. However, the data I need to get is an iframe tag and have a dynamic src value.

I also came up with an idea that use `XML::Parser` since I have the website XML API. However, because of my noobness, I don't know how to get the xml link.

**So my question is:**

1st: How to display or get data from iframe tag

2nd: How to get xml link in from a website.

Here is my code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Getopt::Std;
use XML::Simple;
use WWW::Mechanize;
use HTTP::Cookies;
use LWP::Debug qw(+);


my $username = $opt_u;
my $password = $opt_p;

my $outfile = "out.html";

my $url = "https://t-square.gatech.edu/portal";
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$mech->cookie_jar(HTTP::Cookies->new());
$mech->get($url);

$mech->follow_link(text => "Login", n => 1);
$mech->submit_form(
    form_id=> 'fm1',
    fields => { username    => $username,
                password    => $password
              },
    button => 'submit',
);
$mech->follow_link(text => "CS-2200-A,GR SUM13", n => 1);
my $response = $mech->follow_link(text => "Assignments", n => 1);
$response = $mech->get('https://t-square.gatech.edu/portal/tool/3a34f619-99d1-4548-be57-     9ee977fd8127?panel=Main');
my $content = $response->decoded_content();
my $parser = new XML::Simple;
my $data = $parser->XMLin($content);
print Dumper($data);
my $output_page = $mech->content();
open(OUTFILE, ">$outfile");
print OUTFILE "$output_page";
close(OUTFILE);
```

Here is a piece of the output from my out.htm where the frame src is located.

```
...
<iframe name="Main3a34f619x99d1x4548xbe57x9ee977fd8127"
    id="Main3a34f619x99d1x4548xbe57x9ee977fd8127"
    title="Assignments "
    class ="portletMainIframe"
    height="475"
    width="100%"
    frameborder="0"
    marginwidth="0"
    marginheight="0"
    scrolling="auto"
    src="https://t-square.gatech.edu/portal/tool/3a34f619-99d1-4548-be57-9ee977fd8127?panel=Main">**
</iframe>
...
```

The data that I need is in the src link inside frame tag.

Thank you.

Comment: We need some examples

Comment: What is a "dynamic src value"?

Comment: If there is an API then you should *absolutely* use it over scraping the HTML. What does "get the xml link" mean?

Comment: @Quentin: I meant determine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you get `$output_page`, which is just the `iframe` content apparently, send that string to an HTML parser. Something like my [HTML::SimpleLinkExtor](http://www.metacpan.org/module/HTML::SimpleLinkExtor) might work for you. However, I've been using [Mojo::DOM](http://www.metacpan.org/module/Mojo::DOM) for these things lately. There's also "[How can I extract iframes from text with Perl's Mojo::DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16308019/perl-how-to-extract-iframes-from-text-with-mojodom)".

```
use v5.10;
use Mojo::DOM;

my $html = ...;

say "Src is ", Mojo::DOM->new( $html )->find( 'iframe' )->[0]->{src};
```

However, since you are already using [WWW::Mechanize](http://www.metacpan.org/module/WWW::Mechanize), you should be able to use `find_all_links`:

```
$mech->find_all_links( tag => 'iframe' )
```

Comment: Actually the outout is way longer and have other codes as well.

Comment: The parsers won't care.